# Как лучше сказать: "пошли" или "пойдем(те)"?

Tags: орфография

-

Comment: Попутный вопрос. Используется ли в русских городах в этом смысле слово "айда"? Или это влияние татарского: әйдә, әйдәгез (давай, давайте)? Читается примерно как "айда, айдагез".

Comment: Раньше использовалось. В больших количествах в среде "младшего и среднего школьного". Сейчас давненько не слышал, но я мало общаюсь с этой возрастной прослойкой.   
А происхождение от татарского вполне возможно вне зависимости от того, где и как используют.

Comment: Действительно, некоторые слова, например, "сабантуй", перешли в русский язык, правда, с измененным смыслом. У нас это праздник плуга, который празднуют в конце июня с учетом определенных традиций. А "у русских" - любое застолье.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вообще вопрос более этикетный, чем филологический...
Все формы используются как заменитель отсутвующего в грамматике повелительного наклонения для первого лица множественного числа. 
Но при этом:
Поёдем - обычный вариант, используется как для одного лица (помимо говорящего), так и для нескольких.
Пойдемте - вежливая форма. 
Пошли - обычно приказ, команда и проч., но как разговорная может рассматриваться как аналог пойдём.
Пошлите - просторечно-разговорная форма, со значением полувопроса-подупредложения.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что форма "пошлите" крайне нежелательна и даже недопустима, так как она звучит как омоним словосочетанию "говорите пошлость"

Comment: Я её и не предлагал как допустимую.

Comment: "Пошли" тоже звучит как омоним слову "послать" в повелительном наклонении. Что поделаешь :) Думаю, ничего страшного в таких совпадениях нет. Тем более для разговорной речи.